# Use itemize{} in table

Tags: tables, itemize, enumitem

I want to use `\itemize{}` in a table. Here is a fairly simple set up (`itemize{}` taken from here: http://www.golatex.de/wiki/itemize)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
 &  &  \\
 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\begin{itemize}\\ \item Erstes Element,\begin{itemize},\item Nächste Ebene,\item Item in 2. Ebene,\end{itemize}\\ \item Zweites Element\\ \item Drittes Element,\begin{itemize},\item Die zweite Ebene,\begin{itemize},\item Die dritte Ebene,\item Item in 3 Ebene,\end{itemize},\item Item in 2. Ebene,\item Item in 2. Ebene,\end{itemize}\\ \item Viertes Element\\ \item Fünftes Element\\ \end{itemize}\end{tabular} &  \\
 &  & 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

That does not compile.
However, when I include the `\itemize{}` list "raw", not in a table

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Erstes Element
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Nächste Ebene
        \item Item in 2. Ebene
    \end{itemize}
\item Zweites Element
\item Drittes Element
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Die zweite Ebene
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Die dritte Ebene
                \item Item in 3 Ebene
            \end{itemize}
        \item Item in 2. Ebene
        \item Item in 2. Ebene
    \end{itemize}
\item Viertes Element
\item Fünftes Element
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

It works. Why?

Comment: I've answered for what I believe to be the main erro, but you really ought to post a [minimum working exmaple](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe) we can save and compile -- at the moment I'm getting errors other than the one you report if I just try to wrap it in `\documentlass{article}\begin{document}`...`\end{document}`.  You can also  (from any decent TeX editor) copy-paste the error text rather than screenshots.  If your editor doesn;t let you do that, get a new one or compile from the commandline

Comment: @ChrisH I included a minimal example. I also removed the escaping character `\` but that did not do the trick.

Comment: And now what error do you get?